# Excel VBA Conditional Formating - count the rows of the range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

For every sheet that I use I have to apply a specif design.

1. Colors;
2. Border Colors;
3. Font Colors;
4. Alignment;

Unfortunately, I can not use TABLE DESIGN...

My solution was ...

1. When Row = Even, then interior color type A
2. When Row = ODD, then interior color type B
3. When ROW = 1 (HEADER), then color type C

### Problem

This macro runs ok when the range begins on the first row.

But not always the selected range will start on the first row, right?

That's the problem...

When the selected range **starts on line 2** the macro needs to work like this:

- Header = TYPE C = Line 2 (first row of the range)
- Type A = Line 3 (odd row of the range)
- Type B = Line 4 (even row of the range)

When the selected range **starts on line 3** the macro needs to work like this:

- Header = TYPE C = Line 3 (first row of the range)
- Type A = Line 4 (odd row of the range)
- Type B = Line 5 (even row of the range)

If someone can help me to create a solution?

### Solution by user VBasic2008

If you want to use in your language:

- `PAR` means `EVEN`
- `ÍMPAR` means `ODD`
- `LIN` means `ROW`

```vb
Sub teal_table()

    Const evenFormula As String = "=PAR(LIN())=LIN()"
    Const oddFormula As String = "=ÍMPAR(LIN())=LIN()"
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
    With Selection
        
        ' Set aligment and border to Selected Range
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        .Borders.TintAndShade = 0
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        
        Dim oFormula As String, eFormula As String
        If .Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            eFormula = evenFormula
            oFormula = oddFormula
        Else
            eFormula = oddFormula
            oFormula = evenFormula
        End If
        
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        
        'Apply colors for ROW = EVEN
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=eFormula
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
 
        ' Apply colors for ROW = ODD
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=oFormula
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(245, 245, 245)
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

        ' Apply colors to HEADER
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LIN()=" & .Row
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 128)
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Detect where the first row (headers) is. Then your conditional formulas could be depending on the value of `ROW()-HEADERROW`. If the value is even, Type A, if the value is Odd, Type B (or reverse, your choice)

Comment: Just toggle a boolean `boolean = false` to start then in the loop `boolean = not boolean`. I believe that should work. Now you have your even/odd counter just format according to the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Variable Conditional Formatting (Banded Rows)

- Replace `ODD, EVEN, and ROW` with `ÍMPAR, PAR, and LIN` if necessary. Is it?

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub linhas()

    Const evenFormula As String = "=EVEN(ROW())=ROW()"
    Const oddFormula As String = "=ODD(ROW())=ROW()"
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
    With Selection
        
        ' Set aligment and border to Selected Range
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        .Borders.TintAndShade = 0
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        
        Dim oFormula As String, eFormula As String
        If .Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            eFormula = evenFormula
            oFormula = oddFormula
        Else
            eFormula = oddFormula
            oFormula = evenFormula
        End If
        
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        
        'Apply colors for ROW = EVEN
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=eFormula
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
 
        ' Apply colors for ROW = ODD
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=oFormula
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(245, 245, 245)
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

        ' Apply colors to HEADER
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROW()=" & .Row
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 128)
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 !!!  Unfortunally do not work !  All lines are still white

Comment: Did you (have to) replace all occurrences of `ODD, EVEN, and ROW` according to your language? I mean, I wouldn't post it if it didn't work. Checked once more, it still works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ROWS instead of ROW.

```
With Selection

    .FormatConditions.Delete

    'Apply colors for ROW = EVEN
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISEVEN(ROWS(R" & Selection.Row & "C:RC))"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    ' Apply colors for ROW = ODD
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISODD(ROWS(R" & Selection.Row & "C:RC))"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .Interior.Color = RGB(245, 245, 245)
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    ' Apply colors to HEADER
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROWS(R" & Selection.Row & "C:RC)=1"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 128)
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End With
```

Comment: Hi @norie.  Unfortunally stoped here   __.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISEVEN(ROWS(R" & Selection.Row & "C:RC))"__

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: i am using office 365 (portuguese-BR)